# Linq not in select on datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Hi i've got 2 data tables (bannedlist,countrylist), both contains list of country names and cods in columns cc and country. I am trying to do a query where i can select countries from countrylist table that are not in bannedlist table in order to create a 3rd table.

Any ideas?

I haven't got too far with this.

```
        var ccList = ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable(); 
        var bannedCCList = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable();
        var query = from r in ccList....
```

..

after trying

```
var bannedCCList = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable();
    var query = from r in ccList where !bannedCCList.Any(b => b["cc"] == r["cc"])select r;
```

i still get same country list. banned ones haven't been removed. here is more detail in order to explain more. not sure what i am doing wrong

```
 protected void BindCountryBan(string subd)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = new DB().CountryBan_GetSiteSettings();

        BannedCountryListBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
        BannedCountryListBox.DataValueField = "cc";
        BannedCountryListBox.DataTextField = "country";
        BannedCountryListBox.DataBind();

//bind country list
    var ccList = ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable(); 
    var bannedCCList = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable();
    var query = from r in ccList where !bannedCCList.Any(b => b["cc"] == r["cc"])select r;
    //var query = ccList.Except(bannedCCList); 




    //CountryListBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
    DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    CountryListBox.DataSource = boundTable;
    CountryListBox.DataValueField = "cc";
    CountryListBox.DataTextField = "country";
    CountryListBox.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: After re-thingkink my problem i have relalised that instead of playing andtrying to sort it out, adding a small where to my sql query "Select * from country_list where cc not in(select cc from country_list_banned_countries where subdomain=@subdomain ) order by country asc" i could extract banned countries from country list on server side and bind without struggle. thanks to everyone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Except would work if you use it on sequences of the countries:

```
using System.Linq;
...

    var ccList = from c in ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
                 select c.Field<string>("Country"); 
    var bannedCCList = from c in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                       select c.Field<string>("Country");
    var exceptBanned = ccList.Except(bannedCCList);
```

If you need the full rows where the countries aren't banned, you could try a left outer join:

```
    var ccList = ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable();
    var bannedCCList = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable();
    var exceptBanned = from c in ccList
                       join b in bannedCCList
                         on c.Field<string>("Country") equals b.Field<string>("Country") into j
                       from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where x == null
                       select c;
```

Comment: Thanks! your left outer join works as i expected, one more question if you would. Please see my note on Meta-Knight's answer. I managed to bind result to listbox by converting queryresult to table. Is there any better way to bind?

Comment: Try setting the ListBox's DataTextField and DataValueField values to the names of the fields you want bound. You shouldn't need to copy to a table.

Comment: Please "dahlbyk" i need the second code in VB.Net i have troble with conversion with "http://converter.telerik.com/", thanks in addvance

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Except() LINQ extension method like this:

```
var result = full.Except(banned);
```

However this will work fine with the default comparer of the contained type. Thus if you want to use a specific column like in your example, you might need another approach like:

```
from r in ccList
where !bannedCCList.Any(b => b["cc"] == r["cc"])
select r;
```

Using Except() implies the references are the same in both collections, which I think is not the case with Tables, or correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Kudos! I had to combine a List<EF type> with a data Table and I made slight modifications to your from sample and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var query = ccList.Except(bannedCCList);
```

Comment: You will need:

using System.Linq;

Comment: when i bind query to a listbox all i get is System.Data.DataRow looks like im again doing something wrong

Comment: ok i have converted it to datatable with 
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
but im not usure it is the best way

Comment: While this can also be a solution, it is fast for fewer records, whereas when the list is like 200k, this method will be very slow