# LINQ Except member is missing

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, select

There is a problem in my LINQ query. I am obviously not expert in LINQ
I used ([Linq not in select on datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164770/linq-not-in-select-on-datatable)) from Stack for help

Although my references are correct for LINQ and DatasetExtentions

```vb
Imports System.Data.DataSetExtensions
Imports System.Linq`


Dim productNamex = From products In DBObj.GetDataTable(selectQuery).AsEnumerable() Select products("itemcode")
Dim productNamey = From products In CSVDayTable.AsEnumerable() Select products("item")
Dim ex = productNamex.Except(productNamey)
```

But I am getting an exception at Except function as follows

`{"Public member 'Except' on type 'EnumerableRowCollection(Of Object)' not found."}`

All I wanna do above is `SELECT NOT IN` equivalent of SQL. Anybody got a clue?

Comment: `Dim ex = productNamex.ToList().Except(productNamey)`

Comment: Thanks & Let me give a try

Comment: The issue is that you're selecting the `Item` property in each LINQ query and that property is type `Object`.  I'm guessing that both those columns contain `String` values so you would need to cast as that type somewhere.  You can do that in the original queries or you can do it when you call `Except`, i.e. `productNamex.Cast(Of String)().Except(productNamey.Cast(Of String)())`.

Comment: Now I got this `Public member 'Cast' on type 'EnumerableRowCollection(Of Object)' not found.` I think something is wrong obviously with reference